Converting from AMPL to Pyomo SETOF UNION
I’m attempting to convert an AMPL model to Pyomo, which is something I have no prior experience with.
I’m finding it challenging to adapt to the syntax, especially this part:
"
set YBUS := setof{i in BUS} (i,i) union
setof {(l,k,m) in BRANCH} (k,m) union
setof {(l,k,m) in SWITCH} (k,m) union
setof {(l,k,m) in SWITCH} (m,k) union
setof {(l,k,m) in BRANCH} (m,k);"

In pyomo I've tried this do adapt this setof and union part:
YBUS_elements = list(set((i, i) for i in model.BUS) |
                     set((k, m) for (l, k, m) in model.BRANCH) |
                     set((k, m) for (l, k, m) in model.SWITCH) |
                     set((m, k) for (l, k, m) in model.SWITCH))

model.YBUS = pyo.Set(initialize=YBUS_elements, ordered=True)

But I'm not sure if this is right

It should be easy enough to gin up a little bit of test data to prove it out.  However, the original has 5 components and your translation has only 4, so....  I think you are definitely missing part of the recipe.
